# How do you disable addresses from being automatically linked in an HTML email?

Tags: email, html-email, street-address, phone-number

I am developing an HTML email and I've noticed that some email clients, particularly Mac Mail and the Mail app on iOS 7, automatically wrap addresses and phone numbers in anchor tags.

I've read that adding these meta tags should disable this behavior:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no" />

<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

However, these don't seem to be working and I haven't been able to find the "address=no" anywhere in Apple's documentation. Does it having something to do with the order of meta tags? Does it matter if they are before or after the title tag?

Is there another solution?

Comment: I dont think html emails care about meta tags. You make sure you have a table layout with inline css.

Answer (score 3):

apple mail clients wrap a real `<a>` tag around your addresses and phone numbers upon detection. the workaround is to wrap that address in a classed span and get at that new `<a>` tag in the style tag.

ex:

```
<style="text/css">
.applelinksGrey a {color:#9a9a9a !important; text-decoration:none;}
</style>

<span class="applelinksGrey">25 Court Street, Gary IN 11356</span>
```

Comment: This answer never got marked but it works. I ran into this problem for the nth time and decided to finally find a solution. Came across this, tested, works great across all versions of iOS and is benign in all else.Sure, it makes your email even more verbose but you're using tables, stop complaining.